# How to inherit both Abstract class and Superclass to Subclass

Tags: python, abstract-class, multiple-inheritance, mixins

I am trying to inherit both the Superclass's abstact class and the superclass to a subclass.

Below is the code I am using as example to

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class foo(ABC):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def bar(self):
        pass

    def item(self):
        a = 1
        b = 2
        c = a + b
        print(c)


class bar_for_foo_mixin(foo):
    def __init__(self):
        foo.__init__(self)
    def bar(self):
        print("This should satisfy the abstract method requirement")
        self.item()

fo = foo()
temp = bar_for_foo_mixin(fo)
temp.bar()
```

This throws an exception stating:

```
Can't instantiate abstract class foo with abstract methods bar
```

But If I inheirt to the subclass it work fine with the below code.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class foo(ABC):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def bar(self):
        pass

    def item(self):
        a = 1
        b = 2
        c = a + b
        print(c)


class bar_for_foo_mixin(foo):
    def __init__(self):
        foo.__init__(self)
    def bar(self):
        print("This should satisfy the abstract method requirement")
        self.item()


class myfoo(bar_for_foo_mixin):
    def __init__(self):
        print("myfoo __init__ called")
        self.bar()
        self.item()


obj = myfoo()
```

Could you explain me where I am going worng.

Comment: The problem is the attempt to instantiate `foo` directly. `bar_for_foo_mixin` (it's not really a mixin; it's just a subclass of `foo`) doesn't take any arguments, so why do you think you need `fo` in the first place?

Comment: There's also no multiple inheritance here. You may be thinking of a design where `bar_for_foo_mixin` simply extends `object`, and then `myfoo` inherits from *both* `foo` and `bar_for_foo_mixin`.

Comment: @chepner points out that the purpose of the abstract class is NOT to be instantiated (e.g. fo=foo() should NEVER be used), an abstract class is only there to be inherited from by a subc;ass

Comment: @chepner, Thanks for clarification. I have one more question. Is there a way to access a superclass's method variable in the subclass? Lets say I have a variable named z in new  method bar2() in bar_for_foo_mixin(). Can I access it in the myfoo class?

Comment: If it's a local variable, no. If you want to share data between two methods, you need to do so via instance attributes.

Comment: @chepner, How to access a global variable from superclass to subclass?